# ErrorException in registerController.php line 18: Undefined variable: name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I made a signup form with laravel 5 and im getting this error

ErrorException in registerController.php line 18:
Undefined variable: name

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Hash;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class registerController extends Controller
{
    public function register()
    {
        $request = new Request;

        $user = new User;

        $user->$name = $request->input('nameInputSignup');
        $user->$email = $request->input('emailInputSignup');
        $user->$password = HASH::make($request->input('passwordInputSignup'));
        $user->save();

        return view('index');
    }
}
Route::post('/register' , 'registerController@register');
```

here is my code, can anyone help with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the extra $ from the members of your 'user' object:

```
    $user->name
    $user->email
    $user->password
```